# Add new data-attribute to a input type date in Form builder

Tags: symfony

At the moment i try to get started with symfony2, and are struggling at a task that is certainly easy to accomplish.

I've extended the `DateType` like this:

```
class Datepicker extends DateType
{

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        parent::setDefaultOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'attr'  => [
                'data-format' => 'dd.mm.yy',
                'class' => 'date-picker'
            ]
        ));
    }

}
```

This works like expected. Now I'd like to add a new `data` attribute (`data-min-date="0"`) to this type. For this I make this attemp in the form builder:

```
$builder
            ->add('eventDate', new Datepicker(),
            [
                'attr'  => [
                    'data-min-date' => '0',
                ]
            ])
```

It is kind of logical, that now all attributes except for the new data-attribute are gone.

### My question is:

How can i append a new attribute and let the existing ones untouched? I hope not to have to do something like `array_merge()` here.

### Update

- [Very similar question (maybe even duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058132/modifying-symfony-forms-html-attributes-overriding-a-single-attribute)
- [Github bugtracker discussion](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4833)

Comment: I'm wondering if you have declared the `Datepicker` default options correctly: if you remove the `'attr' => []` from your `eventDate`, do the default options come through as you expect them to?

Comment: @bassplayer7 thank you for your feedback. Yes this works like expected for three forms. Now I just need this one extra attribute for once. I really tried to understand the documentation, but maybe i did something stupid anways ;)

Comment: I was wondering about something like that answer, but couldn't work on it right now. Perhaps later today if it is still a problem. Doing that would still be a little inconvenient as you would have to extend the Twig template to handle `new_attr` as opposed to how it just loops through `attr` by default. But, your options may be limited in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much @bassplayer7 any feedback is welcome. I will keep this up to date, as i'am not really pleased with the given answers in the linked question.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior, simply because default options are defaults for when nothing is set, and if something is set, it should be overwritten.

You can solve this by writing an override for the buildForm method in your Datepicker class, that set the required extra options.

Here is what your class will look like (Not tested)

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class Datepicker extends DateType
{
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        if (!isset($options['attr']) || !is_array($options['attr'])) {
            // Should be an array as defined in the default options, but it doesn't hurt to mae sure
            $options['attr'] = array();
        }

        if (!isset($options['attr']['data-format'])) {
            $options['attr']['data-format'] = 'dd.mm.yy';
        }

        if (!isset($options['attr']['class'])) {
            $options['attr']['class'] = 'date-picker';
        } else {
            // Might want to do more checking to see if it already has a date-picker class
            $options['attr']['class'] .= ' date-picker';
        }
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        parent::setDefaultOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'attr'  => []
        ));
    }

}
```

This way you force certain form options to be set, and still give the possibility for them to be overwritten.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But to be hoenst i think this is a lot of code for a tiny thing to accomplish. I understand that `setDefaultOptions` is certainly not the best place to append new things to an entity. For now it feels easier to just copy all the default attributes (sigh) which is of course no answer for this question at all. I will let this question open for a little while and mess arround with your code. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't believe that "less lines" can actually be a valid point to hack your way around...

Comment: You are right. But i really don't like that i have to know the array keys. It's not about too much lines, but too much duplication.